# Marker in Eclipse editor not showing message

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm building a custom text editor plugin for a domain specific language in Eclipse.

I can detect errors in the format of the editor contents and want to use eclipse's marker's to point out the errors to the user.

I have the following code in the plugin:

```java
public static void createMarkerForResource(int linenumber, String message) throws CoreException {
    IResource resource = getFile();
    createMarkerForResource(resource, linenumber, message);
  }

  public static void createMarkerForResource(IResource resource, int linenumber, String message)
      throws CoreException {
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    MarkerUtilities.setLineNumber(map, linenumber);
    MarkerUtilities.setMessage(map, message); 
    MarkerUtilities.createMarker(resource, map, IMarker.PROBLEM);
    IMarker[] markers = resource.findMarkers(null, true, IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE);
    for (IMarker marker : markers){
      System.out.println("Marker contents"+MarkerUtilities.getMessage(marker));
    } 
  }
```

I run this code with the command:

```java
createMarkerForResource(2, "hello");
```

This successfully gives me an image on the correct line

[image]

and if I hover over it, I get a 'you can click this thing' cursor. **But I can't get the message to turn up.**

The message has definitely been placed, because the:

```java
for (IMarker marker : markers){
          System.out.println("Marker contents"+MarkerUtilities.getMessage(marker));
        }
```

code produces the "Marker contentshello" output as expected.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

The message *is* appearing in the problem view:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Njol is correct and works for me (Eclipse Neon.1).

But two additional recommendations:

1. I am reusing a created field, so annotation hoover is not always new created (getter... not create method)
2. Default annotation hoover does show all annotations. So when you want only markers to be shown (and no others - e.g. Diff annotations from GIT) you should override isIncluded as in my following example.

Example:

```java
    import org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewerConfiguration;
        ...
        public class MySourceViewerConfiguration extends SourceViewerConfiguration {
        ...
    
            private IAnnotationHover annotationHoover;
        ...
    
            public MySourceViewerConfiguration(){
              this.annotationHoover=new MyAnnotationHoover();
            }
        ...
            @Override
            public IAnnotationHover getAnnotationHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
            return annotationHoover;
        }
    }
```

And here the annotation hoover class

```java
    private class MyAnnotationHoover extends DefaultAnnotationHover{
        @Override
        protected boolean isIncluded(Annotation annotation) {
             if (annotation instanceof MarkerAnnotation){
                    return true;
             }
             /* we do not support other annotations than markers*/
             return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a proper `IAnnotationHover`, which can e.g. be defined in your `SourceViewerConfiguration` like this:

```
@Override
public IAnnotationHover getAnnotationHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
    return new DefaultAnnotationHover(false);
}
```